# The error stated ->Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php

The error states:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array
```

Code:

```php
   $sqlselect=mysqli_query($connection_db, "SELECT * FROM chromebook WHERE chromebook.LokasiCb like '%".$LokasiCb."%'");
    //Langkah#4: Bina table heading/ kepala jadual
    echo "<center><table border='1'><tr>
        <th>Bil</th>
        <th>Kod Daftar</th>
        <th>Nama Chrome Book</th>
        <th>Lokasi Chrome Book</th>
        <th>Padam</th>
        </tr></center>";

    $pembilang=1;
    //Langkah#5: Mendapatkan data daripada pangkalan data dan memaparkan data dalam jadual

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlselect))
    {
     echo"<tr>
      <td align='center'>".$pembilang."</td>
      <td align='center'>".$row['KodDaftar']."</td>
      <td align='center'>".$row['NamaCb']."</td>
      <td align='center'>".$row['LokasiCb']."</td>
     <td><a href='hapus.php?KodDaftar=$sqlselect[KodDaftar]&NamaCb&LokasiCb=$sqlselect[NamaCb]'>Padam</a></td>
      </tr>";
    $pembilang++; //menambah pembilang
    }
    echo"</table>";
}
```

Comment: Try `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that in your code you use

$sqlselect[KodDaftar] and this causes the problem $sqlselect in this case is actually a mysqli_result object not an associative array. Therefore, the error.

Change this line

```
<td align='center'>".$row['LokasiCb']."</td>
 <td><a href='hapus.php?KodDaftar=$sqlselect[KodDaftar]&NamaCb&LokasiCb=$sqlselect[NamaCb]'>Padam</a></td>
  </tr>";
```

to

```
<td align='center'>".$row['LokasiCb']."</td>
 <td><a href='hapus.php?KodDaftar=".$row['KodDaftar']."&NamaCb&LokasiCb=".$row['NamaCb']."'>Padam</a></td>
  </tr>";
```

That will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Within your link href, you have values like this:

$sqlselect[KodDaftar] and $sqlselect[NamaCb]

...which should be $row not $sqlselect.

The $sqlselect is your result set not your individual row.